# Replace Value in a JSON file

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a json arm template (file.json as an example):

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "parameter1": {
            "value": "test"
        },
        "patameter2": {
            "value": "test"
        },
        "parameter3": {
            "value": "test".   (should be "defaultValue: "")
        }
    }
}
```

I have to replace all values to str"" by python script. Could someone advise me on that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your example is not valid json.

Comment: Here is my valid json for Aure Resource manager

Comment: All of those values are already strings, so I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: sorry for the misunderstandings. I just edit the question.

Answer (score 0):

So what I think you're saying is you want to set all `"value":""`
You can use the [`json` python library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) and iterate over all `parameters` and set the `value` to `""`